# Assistance Required to select and set different OAuth ClientId and ClientSecret credentials for all views

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I am working on my first ever Django project and have been trying to do something that I have been stuck with for weeks and looking for any assistance, please.

each of my views uses a CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET and I have a page with a drop-down to select one of the OAuth Accounts that I would like to use.

[Menu Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/atbi9.png)

**HTML Snippet**

```html
    <h2>Select Menu</h2>
            <p>To style a select menu in Bootstrap 5, add the .form-select class to the select element:</p>
              <label for="cust" class="form-label">Select list (select one):</label>
              <select class="form-select" id="cust" name="customer">
                <option>Auth 1</option>
                <option>Auth 2</option>
                <option>Auth 3</option>
                <option>Auth 4</option>
              </select>
              <input type="submit" value="click" class="btn btn-primary">
```

**Views.py snippet**

```py
    def data(request):

        # OAuth when using Client Credentials
        CLIENT_ID = CLIENT_ID
        CLIENT_SECRET = CLIENT_SECRET

    def getdata(request):
        
        # OAuth when using Client Credentials
        CLIENT_ID = CLIENT_ID
        CLIENT_SECRET = CLIENT_SECRET
```

When an Auth Selection is made via the dropdown, I would like to set the `CIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` to be used for all of my views. Ultimately I would like to use dotenv as well.

I am struggling to get the selection and then set the `CIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` to each view.

Thank you very much.

Comment: if you don't use JavaScript to send it back then you have to put it in `<form> </form>`

Comment: you should get it as `request.form['"customer"]` - ie. `Auth 1` - and use global dict to select correct value - `authorizations = {"Auth 1": (CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET), "Auth 2": (other_CLIENT_ID, other_CLIENT_SECRET), ...}` And all `CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET` you could read from file at start (ie. from JSON file)

Comment: Hi @furas, 

Thank you. I have managed to get the user's choice by using a Django-Form, Styled with widget_tweaks.

This is what I have got now.

**forms.py**

`from django import forms
from django.forms import TextInput, EmailInput

class CustomerAccessForm(forms.Form):
    customer = forms.ChoiceField(label='Customer', choices=[('Auth1', 'Auth1'), ('Auth2', 'Auth2'), ('Auth3', 'Auth3')])`

Comment: **my html file and form**

 `<form action="{% url 'customeraccess' %}" method="POST">
            <div class="form-group">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% for field in form %}
                {{ field.errors }}
                {{ field.label_tag }}
                {% render_field field class="form-control" %}
            </div>
                {% endfor %}
            <div class="text-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">
            </div>
        </form>`

Comment: **my views.py file**

`def customeraccess(request):
    form = CustomerAccessForm() # Declare form as a local variable
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filled_form = CustomerAccessForm(request.POST)
        if filled_form.is_valid():
            selection = 'Customer selected is %s' % filled_form.cleaned_data['customer']
            new_Form = CustomerAccessForm()
            return render(request, 'home/customeraccess.html', {'form': new_Form, 'selection': selection})

Comment: I am able to get the choice and save it in the *selection* variable.
How would I go about using the global dict to set it for all of my views?

Comment: I have been able to figure it out. Thank you for your assistance.